# how to use user defined macro in target prerequisites

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have a Makefile like this

```
year = $(shell echo $(1) | cut -c 1-4)
month = $(shell echo $(1) | cut -c 5-6)
day = $(shell echo $(1) | cut -c 7-8)

.SECONDARY.
%/foo.md : /data/%/FOO_PATTERN.*
      ./foo_input_reader $^ | ./foo_processor > $@ 2> $(dir $@)/foo.log
```

When I call
**make 20220310/foo.md**, prerequisites of the target expand to

```
/data/20220310/FOO_PATTERN.*
```

and my rule creates **20220310/foo.md** file using the following command

```
./foo_input_reader /data/20220310/FOO_PATTERN.* | ./foo_processor > 20220310/foo.md 2> 20220310/foo.log
```

What I am trying to achieve now is to change prerequisites section of the rule in a way that it expands to this

```
/data/YYYY/MM/DD/FOO_PATTERN.*
```

instead of

```
/data/YYYYMMDD/FOO_PATTERN.*
```

I was hoping to achieve this by calling year, month and day macros I defined (see the beginning of my Makefile) in prerequisites section of the rule, so have there something like

```
%/foo.md : /data/$(call year,$@)/$(call month,$@)/$(call day,$@)/FOO_PATTERN.* 
      ./foo_input_reader $^ | ./foo_processor > $@ 2> $(dir $@)/foo.log
```

but this doesn't work, I think because variable and function references in the list of prerequisites are immediately expanded during the read phase (http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles).

I am sure however that this should be possible?
Can you please advice if this is possible and if yes, what would be the right way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you actually have a file named `/data/2022/03/10/FOO_PATTERN.*`? I think you misunderstand how wildcards work in Make.

Comment: I don't have file called /data/2022/03/10/FOO_PATTERN.*, I used that expression to write less text. When I use /data/%/FOO_PATTERN.* as prerequisite and call make 20220310/foo.md, $^ var will contain files with FOO_PATTERN prefix from directory /data/20220310/, so the input of foo_input_reader will be all those files (not exactly /data/20220310/FOO_PATTERN.*).What I am trying to achieve is to be able to call for example 20220310/foo.md but tell make that this target depends on files that start with FOO_PATTERN prefix and are located under /data/2022/03/10/ directory,and use $^ to refer to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I think that you misunderstand how '*' works in a makefile, but that doesn't matter for now.)

First, instead of three `cut` commands, I suggest you use one `sed` command. This is not necessary, but I think it makes things tidier.

```
DATA_PATH = $(shell echo $(1) | sed "s|\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)|data/\1/\2/\3/FOO_PATTERN.*|")
```

Second, it's not `.SECONDARY.`, it's `.SECONDEXPANSION:`.

Third, Secondary Expansion doesn't mean that there's no Primary Expansion. In the *first* expansion, the automatic variables (like `$@`) in the prerequisite list have no value and expands to nothing, so anything done in the second expansion comes too late. We can prevent this by escaping variables with `$`:

```
%/foo.md: $$(call DATA_PATH,$$*)
    @echo building $@ from $^
    ./foo_input_reader $^ ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Beta, this answers my question. The question of '*' I think is a separate one so perhaps it worth discussing it in some other thread. I will mark your answer accepted.